# ArrayAdapter's getView and AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-annotations

I extend the `ArrayAdapter` class that have `getView(...)` method. Inside it I write something like this:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    ...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
    }   
    // ...
    // LOTS of findViewById, onClickListeners, runOnUiThread methods etc.
    // ...

    return v;
}

...
}
```

So, using `AndroidAnnotations` in `Activity` I can easily implement `findViewById`, `listeners` etc.

But how can I do it in this case, when extending `ArrayAdapter`, using `AndroidAnnotations` (or maybe any other framework that will not make spaghetti code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this following link:

https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Adapters-and-lists

This should explain how to use Adapters with Androidannotations